# Matlab: random integers from a range with no repetition

Tags: matlab, random, integer, range

I want to get an array with randomized integer included in range with no repeat, I used :

```
randperm(15,3)
```

output is :

```
8, 10, 12
```

This function not use a range, I would like to random values only from 10 e.g.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, it is unclear. What range were you expecting when you only supply the one value (15)? Can't you simply use `a - 1 + randperm( b-a+1, k )`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the Statistics toolbox, you can use [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) without replacement.

```
% MATLAB R2017a
LB = 3;   % lower bound of range (integer)
UB = 17;  % upper bound of range (integer),  UB > LB
randsample(LB:UB,3,'false')
```

@[Wolfie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3978545/wolfie)'s method using [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) works well and **requires no toolbox**.

```
LB - 1 + randperm(UB-LB+1,3)
```

---

Notice that [`randi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) works well for uniformly distributed (discrete uniform) integers in a range but it samples *with replacement* (can give duplicates). This requires no toolbox to my knowledge but would require combining with a procedure to remove duplicates and resample until all integers were unique.

```
randi([LB UB],3,1)
```

Note: will remove @[Wolfie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3978545/wolfie)'s method if @Wolfie posts it as answer or can make this answer community wiki based on consensus.